# How can I get selected "itemsid " from spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

When I select any Item from spinner, I get position, Item Name. When I will click on any Item, I need this ItemId. What can I do?

I have used retrofit. I get a data list from webservice.

```
List<Zone> zonelst=response.body().getZoneslist();
```

zonelst contain zid and zname .

I have loaded "items"(zname) to the spinner. When I will click on any Items (zname), I need itemsid(zid).

```
for(int i=0; i<zonelst.size(); i++){
//Storing names to string array
items[i] = zonelst.get(i).getZname();
itemsid[i]=zonelst.get(i).getZid();
}
```

MODEL:

```
    public class Zone {
    @SerializedName("ZID")
    private String zid;
    @SerializedName("ZName")
    private String zname;

    public Zone(String zid, String zname) {
        this.zid = zid;
        this.zname = zname;
    }

    public String getZid() {
        return zid;
    }

    public void setZid(String zid) {
        this.zid = zid;
    }

    public String getZname() {
        return zname;
    }

    public void setZname(String zname) {
        this.zname = zname;
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY:

ZoneApiInterface apiService=OperatingApiClient.getClient().create(ZoneApiInterface.class);

```
Call<ZoneApiResponse> call = apiService.getZoneInfoList();
call.enqueue(new Callback<ZoneApiResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ZoneApiResponse> call, Response<ZoneApiResponse> response) {
        List<Zone> zonelst=response.body().getZoneslist();
        Log.d(TAG,"Number of Zone received1: "+zonelst.size());

        //*********DROPDOWN******************************************************

        //String array to store all the zone names
        String[] items = new String[zonelst.size()];
        String[] itemsid = new String[zonelst.size()];

        //Traversing through the whole list to get all the names
        for(int i=0; i<zonelst.size(); i++){
            //Storing names to string array
            items[i] = zonelst.get(i).getZname();
            itemsid[i]=zonelst.get(i).getZid();
        }


        final Spinner spnrZone=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerZone);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items); //getApplication()
        //setting adapter to spinner
        spnrZone.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Creating an array adapter for list view


        spnrZone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int Hold = spnrZone.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Position is = "+Hold, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String N=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Name = "+N, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ZoneApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        // Log error here since request failed
        Log.e(TAG,t.toString());

    }
});
```

Comment: If you have the position, you can simply fetch the item from the list at the given position, and fetch it's ID..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42198867/5612708) if you want to stay with your original code.

But this is not optimised piece of code.

After getting the response you copy all the znames and zids to the array which takes extra space as well as time (For-loop).

I would recommend an alternate approach.

Override the `toString` method in your `Zone` model. Add this to your `Zone` model :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getZname();
}
```

In you ACTIVITY :

```
Call<ZoneApiResponse> call = apiService.getZoneInfoList();
call.enqueue(new Callback<ZoneApiResponse>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ZoneApiResponse> call, Response<ZoneApiResponse> response) {
    List<Zone> zonelst=response.body().getZoneslist();
    Log.d(TAG,"Number of Zone received1: "+zonelst.size());

    //*********DROPDOWN******************************************************

    final Spinner spnrZone=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerZone);
    ArrayAdapter<Zone> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Zone>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,zonelst); //getApplication()
    //setting adapter to spinner
    spnrZone.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Creating an array adapter for list view


    spnrZone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Zone z = (Zone) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            int Hold = spnrZone.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Position is = "+Hold, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String N = z.getZname();
            String zid = z.getZid();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Name = "+N+",Item ID = "+zid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ZoneApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    // Log error here since request failed
    Log.e(TAG,t.toString());

}
});
```

Comment: If I follow your code, I get proper value of "String N = z.getZname();", But Spinner was loaded with wrong value.

Comment: May I know what values is it loading?

Comment: Spinner was loaded with wrong value:

com.nitolniloy.operating.model.Zone@d1..
com.nitolniloy.operating.model.Zone@5f..
com.nitolniloy.operating.model.Zone@58..
com.nitolniloy.operating.model.Zone@95..


If I apply " itemsid[position]; " . These are real value-
Zone1
Zone2
Zone3
Zone4

Comment: Did you Override the toString method in your `Zone` class ?

Comment: Thank you. It works now.

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getZname();
}


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Zone>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,zonelst);

Comment: Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
spnrZone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int Hold = spnrZone.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Position is = "+Hold, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String N=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Name = "+N, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String id=itemsid[position];  //simply get its id (String or int use whatev er its type)
            }
```

use `itemsid[position];`